# Reshape the data from long to wide format

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I am looking for swift way of reshaping the data from long to wide format. Right now I have tried a code with nest for loops, though the job gets done, it takes a long time to generate the output.

```
SN NN EE Service_tier
A  B  C  economy
B  C  C  economy
P  Q  R  regular
Q  S  R  regular
S  R  R  regular
H  I  L  economy
I  J  L  economy
J  K  L  economy
K  L  L  economy
```

The output expected is as below

```
SN hop1 hop2 hop3 hop4 service_tier
A   B    C              economy
P   Q    S    R         regular
H   I    J    K    L    economy
```

currently the below code gets the job done. Am sure there is an effective and clean way to do this.

```
for (i in 1:lasrow){
  sn <- raw_d[i,1]
  nn <- raw_d[i,2]
  en <- raw_d[i,3]

  lc <- 1

  if(nn == en){
    d[lr,lc]<-sn
    d[lr,lc+1]<-nn
    d[lr,lc+2]<-en
    lr <- lr+1
  }
  else{
    while(nn!=en){
      d[lr,lc]<-sn
      lc <- lc+1
      next_d <- filter(raw_d,raw_d$SN==sn,raw_d$EN==en)
      if(dim(next_d)[1]==0){
        d[lr,lc]<-"broken bf"
        lc <- lc+1
        break
      }else{
        sn <- next_d$NN
        nn <- next_d$NN
        }
      }
    d[lr,lc]<-en
    lr<-lr+1
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to stand that your sets are mutually exclusive, for example, regular = {P, Q, R, S} but P,Q,R, and S are part of no other "set". Will this always be true? Could "A" ever be part of regular and economy? The proper method to widen this data will depend on your answer.

Comment: economy = {P,Q,R,S} can appear in economy as well but for a give P and S we will have only one path not multiple paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crucial point here is to identify which rows belong to which group. The answers by [Ronak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56371064/3817004) and [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56371193/3817004) both use `rleid(Service_tier)` assuming that a change in `Service_tier` indicate the begin of a new group.

This might be suggested by the sample dataset but cannot be taken as guaranteed. IMHO, `Service_tier` is rather an attribute than a key. As a matter of fact, the OP is testing for `NN == EE` in his code snippet to switch to a new group.

In the data.table solutions below, grouping is determined by `cumsum(shift(NN == EE, fill = TRUE))` which tests for equality fo `NN` and `EE`, lags the result to the next row where the next group starts, and enumerates the groups by counting `TRUE` using `cumsum()`.

In the simplified version (without reshaping), the hops are aggregated by the `toString()` function:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, .(SN = first(SN), hops = toString(NN), Service_tier = first(Service_tier)), 
  by = .(grp = cumsum(shift(NN == EE, fill = TRUE)))][]
```

> ```
>    grp SN       hops Service_tier
> 1:   1  A       B, C      economy
> 2:   2  P    Q, S, R      regular
> 3:   3  H I, J, K, L      economy
> ```

For reshaping from long to wide format, `dcast()` is used:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)   # piping used to improve readability
w <- setDT(d)[, .(SN = first(SN), hops = NN, Service_tier = first(Service_tier)), 
  by = .(grp = cumsum(shift(NN == EE, fill = TRUE)))] %>% 
  dcast(grp + ... ~ rowid(grp, prefix = "hop"), value.var = "hops", fill = "")  %>%  
  setcolorder(c(1:2, 4:ncol(.), 3))

w
```

> ```
>    grp SN hop1 hop2 hop3 hop4 Service_tier
> 1:   1  A    B    C                economy
> 2:   2  P    Q    S    R           regular
> 3:   3  H    I    J    K    L      economy
> ```

`setcolorder()` is used to rearrange columns in the order expected by the OP. This is done *in-place*, i.e., without copying the whole data object.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)

d <- fread("SN NN EE Service_tier
A  B  C  economy
B  C  C  economy
P  Q  R  regular
Q  S  R  regular
S  R  R  regular
H  I  L  economy
I  J  L  economy
J  K  L  economy
K  L  L  economy")
```

Comment: I am getting an error...Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , .(SN = first(SN), hops = toString(NN), Service_tier = first(Service_tier)),  : 
  unused argument (by = .(grp = cumsum(shift(NN == EE, fill = TRUE))))

Comment: @VasukiRao It seems I might have forgotten to coerce `d` to data.table using `setDT(d)`. I have amended the code. Please, tray again. And thank you for reporting.

Comment: when i run the code, Error in ncol(w) : object 'w' not found

Comment: My bad. Another copy & paste error. Please, see amended code.

Comment: great, works flawlessly, every interesting solution compared to for loop

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a unique sequence using `rleid` from `data.table`, `gather` the dataframe to long format, remove the duplicates from each group, assign column names and `spread` it back to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = data.table::rleid(Service_tier)) %>%
  gather(key, value, -Service_tier, -row) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(value)) %>%
  mutate(key = c("SN", paste0("hop", 1:(n() - 1)))) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  select(SN, starts_with("hop"), Service_tier)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  SN    hop1  hop2  hop3  hop4  Service_tier
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <fct>       
#1  A     B     C     NA    NA    economy     
#2  H     I     J     K     L     economy     
#3  P     Q     S     R     NA    regular
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'dat.table' (`setDT(df1)`, grouped by `rleid` on the 'Service_tier', change the value of 'SN' to `first` element grouped by 'grp', then grouped by 'Service_tier', 'SN', get the `unique` element of Subset of Data.table and `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1)[, SN := first(SN), rleid(Service_tier)][, 
    unique(unlist(.SD)), .(SN, Service_tier)], 
    SN + Service_tier ~ paste0("hop", rowid(SN)), value.var = "V1", fill = "")
#  SN Service_tier hop1 hop2 hop3 hop4
#1:  A      economy    B    C          
#2:  H      economy    I    J    K    L
#3:  P      regular    Q    S    R
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SN = c("A", "B", "P", "Q", "S", "H", "I", "J", 
"K"), NN = c("B", "C", "Q", "S", "R", "I", "J", "K", "L"), EE = c("C", 
"C", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L"), Service_tier = c("economy", 
"economy", "regular", "regular", "regular", "economy", "economy", 
"economy", "economy")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```